# Spring application is not loading in tomcat 7.0.47 but is loading in Tomcat 7.0.34 within Eclipse Kepler

Tags: spring, tomcat7

Till now i was using tomcat 7.0.34 and my spring application was loading perfectly. Yesterday i decided to use 7.0.47 and the container is not loading anymore my application. If i switch back to 34 version it works again. I tested on 7.0.52 and the same problem is there.

Not sure what can be the issue.

StackTrace

```
Mrz 28, 2014 11:03:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;d:\imagemagick-6.3.9-q8;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q16;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WBEM;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\V1.0\;C:\PROGRAM FILES\THINKPAD\BLUETOOTH SOFTWARE\;C:\PROGRAM FILES\THINKPAD\BLUETOOTH SOFTWARE\SYSWOW64;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Network Monitor 3\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Services\IPT\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51;D:\apache-cassandra-2.0.5;D:\maven/bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;.
Mrz 28, 2014 11:03:28 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:daydiary' did not find a matching property.
Mrz 28, 2014 11:03:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mrz 28, 2014 11:03:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mrz 28, 2014 11:03:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 756 ms
Mrz 28, 2014 11:03:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mrz 28, 2014 11:03:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
Mrz 28, 2014 11:03:30 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mrz 28, 2014 11:03:30 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mrz 28, 2014 11:03:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2201 ms
```

The problem i see is my WebApplicationInitializer implementation is not detected somehow. What can be the cause for this.?
I am using JDK 7 , spring 4.0.2

Comment: What does your stack trace look like?

Comment: We are running jdk 7.0_51, tomcat 7.0.52, Spring 4.0.2.RELEASE with WebAppInitializer. Runs like a charm. Maybe some problem with the kepler integration?

Comment: No i was using indigo yesterday and the same problem was there....than i switched to kepler...same problem here..I am using exact same configuration like yours..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man !.... I just deleted the web.xml file and the WebApplicationInitializer is now loaded.
Previously i had both of them. Just not sure if you can have both with this kind of configuration but looks like you cannot....

Comment: I have the same problem. But I still can not solve this problem after deleted web.xml....